# How to use the pipe operator with tuples and anonymous functions in Julia?

Tags: pipe, tuples, anonymous-function, julia

I am trying to use tuples with the pipe operator, `|>` along with an anonymous function like

`(1,2)  |>  (x,y) -> x^2 + y^2`

but receiving an error message:

```
wrong number of arguments
while loading In[59], in expression starting on line 1

 in anonymous at In[59]:1
 in |> at operators.jl:178
```

Apparently, the `(1,2)` tuple does not get mapped to `(x,y)`.

After a little bit of trying I realized I can circumvent the problem by

`(1,2)  |>  x -> x[1]^2 + x[2]^2`

but the latter is not as elegant as the first way in certain contexts. What does the syntax should look like if I wanted to map `(1,2)` to `(x,y)` in the first, `F#` way?

Comment: Here is a [related Google-Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-dev/q_mPbNwVXi0).

Comment: For anyone coming to this question now (i.e. any time after Julia 1.0), note that most of the answers here are **not recommended** procedure, as they commit [type piracy](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Avoid-type-piracy). [James Kai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73285134/) below is the only correct idiomatic answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new method for the generic function `|>` that takes a tuple of arguments and maps it to the formal parameters of the function, something like this:

```rb
julia> Base.|>(xs::Tuple, f) = f(xs...)
|> (generic function with 7 methods)

julia> let
           x = 1
           y = 2

           # just messing around...
           (x, y) |> (x, y) -> (2x, 5y) |>
                     divrem             |>
                     complex            |>
                     x -> (x.re, x.im)  |>
                     divrem             |>
                     (x...) -> [x...]   |>
                     sum                |>
                     float

       end
0.0
```

Answer (score 5):

Without pipelining you would use the splat operator in this situation

```
((x,y) -> x^2 + y^2)((1,2)...)
```

With pipelining

```
julia> (1,2)...  |>  (x,y) -> x^2 + y^2
ERROR: MethodError: `|>` has no method matching |>(::Int32, ::Int32, ::Function)
```

So you could extend |> to handle two arguments

```
import Base.|>
|>(x,y,f) = f(x,y)
```

Voila

```
julia> (1,2)...  |>  (x,y) -> x^2 + y^2
5
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using Julia v1.7

According to Julia's documentation:

> For anonymous functions, destructuring a single tuple requires an extra comma

e.g.,

```
# map((a,b)->(5*a + 3*b), [(1,2), (3,4)]) # MethodError
  map(((a,b),)->(5*a + 3*b), [(1,2), (3,4)]) # Correct (11,27)
```

This also applies to tuple destructuring in anonymous function with pipe operator. Use Original author's example, changing from

```
(1,2)  |>  (x,y) -> x^2 + y^2
```

to

```
(1,2)  |>  ((x,y),) -> x^2 + y^2
```

should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

What about a more general approach?

`|>(args...) = args[end](args[1:end-1]...)`

`(1, 2, 3)... |> (x, y, z) -> x + y * z`
evaluates to `7`

broadcasting is a bit awkward, though:

`[(1,2), (3,4)] .|> x -> x... .|> (x, y) -> x + y`

EDIT:

Defining

```
import Base.|>

|>(args...) = args[end](args[1:end-1]...)
→(x, y) = |>(x..., y)
```

Allows you to write
`[(1,2), (3,4)] .→ (x, y) -> x + y`